# What OS does iPod Nano 6G/7G Run?

Tags: operating-system, ipod

Per numerous articles I've read online, the 6 and 7 generation iPod nano does not run iOS.

[Cult of Mac: Touchscreen iPod Nano Does Not Run iOS](http://www.cultofmac.com/57467/apple-touchscreen-ipod-nano-does-not-run-ios/)

If this is the case, I'd love to know what OS they are actually running. Is it something based on iOS/OS X, or is it a whole different custom OS?

Comment: Apple doesn't tell (they never do), and the nano didn't attract enough attention to be hacked. I'm almost certain you couldn't do anything useful with that knowledge anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this article (and my admittedly fragile memory) the original iPods (i.e. before the iPhone/iPod touch) all ran an operating system called 'Pixo':

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixo

So it is not at all related even to Darwin. The newer revisions of the original iPod generation (nano etc.) essentially were just "re-skinned" to look more like iOS.

Comment: great find! isn't that amazing, 100 million+ devices using this OS and no one even knows its name...

Comment: I think the "Apple History" biography book mentions the ruckus that happened when Apple went with Forstall's (Serlet's?) plan to go with a MacOS-derived OS instead of using Fadell & Co's iPod OS.

Answer (score 2):

The IPod Nano 7G runs 1.0.2 PC, this is a IOS styled OS but is not the a proper IOS. I don't know if there will be a software update from Itunes for it,but you never know!

Hope this answered your question,
Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just some sort of embedded OS that Apple never bothered to tell us about. It isn't iOS or Mac OSX, because that would take way too much computing power and drive up the price and power usage. It's probably just an embedded Mach system.

Some more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod#Software

Answer (score 0):

The iPod Nano 7 uses 1.0.3 PC as of 8 January 2014. I do not know the underlying kernel, I think it is Darwin, however.

Answer (score -4):

- ipod nano 6gen is running ios 3.0.9
- ipod nano 7gen is running ios 3.9.9
- ipod nano 5gen is running ios 2.9.9
- ipod touch 2 is ios 4.2.1
- ipod touch 3 is ios 5.0.1
- ipod touch 4 is ios 6.1.3

Comment: This was not at all what I was asking.  I am interested in the details of the underlying kernel/OS that Apple uses for iPod Nano.  It is NOT iOS.